# Listen for class change on nav

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mutation-observers

I have setup an event listener to determine whether a class attribute has changed, however this is only currently working on the first element of the menu. This needs to be triggered on each element with the specified class when it changes too.

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.elementskit-megamenu-panel')
const options = {
    attributes: true
}
function callback(mutationList, observer) {
    mutationList.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
        // handle class change
        console.log(mutation.target.className);
        }
    })
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
observer.observe(menu, options)
```

markup

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Item</a>
        <div class="elementskit-megamenu-panel"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item</a>
        <div class="elementskit-megamenu-panel"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item</a>
        <div class="elementskit-megamenu-panel"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you do not include children/subtree in the options https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe

Comment: unfortunately including subtree in options didn't resolve this.

Comment: The site may fully recreate (or re-append) the other elements, which you can detect via `childList: true`.

Comment: I did try applying these parameters without success.
[https://jsfiddle.net/pfk1h7jq/](https://jsfiddle.net/pfk1h7jq/)

Comment: Are you sure that the menu does not trigger events to tell you that it changed?

Comment: I have confirmed this with the original vendor and they have confirmed there is no event listener / trigger currently in place.